# recursion-consecutive numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

what is the number of subsets of the set {k∈N|1≤k≤n} with no two consecutive numbers?
The answer says: $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$ with the starting conditions: $$a_0=1, a_1=2$$1. why does $a_1=2$? $$$$ 2. How does this recursion was created, I understand that if $a_n$ mean all the places with no consecutive numbers so, $a_{n-1}$ come from the fact that after the first place all those places satisfy this condition, but why there is need to "look" at what happen after the two places?

Comment: Do you understand why $a_0=1$? If you do, $a_1=2$ is pretty much the same.

Comment: @Git Gud does $a_0=1$ mean the empty series? so just one option?

Answer (score 3):

$a_1=2$ because if $n=1$ you can either have $\emptyset$ or $\{1\}$

For the recursion, to form a subset from $n$, you can either have a subset of $n-1$ and not take element $n$ or you can have a subset of $n-2$, not take $n-1$ and take $n$.  You should convince yourself that this accounts for all the subsets of $n$ that don't have two in a row.

Comment: but why does not this set has all 10 options for all digits?

Comment: "∅ or {1}" for what they stand for in this question?

Comment: First comment:  we are not talking about digits, we are talking about numbers.  If $n=6, \{1,3,6\}$ would be a legal subset, but $\{1,3,4,6\}$ would not because of the $3$ and $4$.  Second comment:  $\emptyset$ is the empty set.  $\{1\}$ is the set with only $1$ as a member.  For $n=1$, that is your set.  These two are the legal subsets.

Comment: @  Ross Millikan from your answer how can I see the expression  $a_n=a_{n−1}+a_{n−2}$

Comment: In my second paragraph I show how to separate the legal subsets into two groups.  The first are just the legal subsets taken from $n-1$, so there are $a_{n-1}$ of them.  The second are in correspondence with the legal subsets taken from $n-2$, so there are $a_{n-2}$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

Subsets of a set include the empty set, marked with $∅$ or $\{∅\}$.

- $n=0:$ The empty set $\{∅\}$ has one subset: $\{∅\}$. So $a_0=1$.
- $n=1:$ The set $\{1\}$ has 2 subsets: $\{1\}$ and $\{∅\}$. So $a_1=2$.

For a general $n$ you can decide that the first number is used or that it is not used in the subset.

- $1^{st}$ number **not** used: there are $n-1$ numbers left and $a_{n-1}$ subsets.
- $1^{st}$ number **is** used: we cannot take the number next to $1^{st}$ and we're left with $a_{n-2}$ possibilities.

Overall we combine these two alternatives to obtain the identity in question:
$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$